# Ghidra: Prepend memory segment in assembly listing view

Tags: ghidra

Ida prepends the memory segment before each instruction. How can it be added in Ghidra ? I've already tried to edit the listing fields without success as no option fits my need.

What I would like

`.text:00000000 c3 ret ...`

What I currently have

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well, rubber ducking really works.

I found it myself, go to `Edit > Tool Options > Listing Fields > Address Field` and check `Show Block Name`

Comment: I will just add that the segment name can be changed in `Window > Memory Map`